# Doctrine: Value of mappedBy ignored in OneToMany Association

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, doctrine-orm, entity

I set up a simple User->Comment association in Doctrine, simple OneToMany (One User can write many Comments).

All works find, but i found a strange behavior of Doctrine. First some Code:

**User Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User extends EntityAbstract {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $_id;

    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Comment", mappedBy="TodayIsASunnyDay")
     *                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ WTF
     */
    protected $_commentsAuthored;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->_commentsAuthored = 
            new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
}
```

**Comment Entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="comments")
 */
class Comment extends EntityAbstract {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $_id;

    /**
     * @var User
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     *
     */
    protected $_author;
}
```

In User, doctrine wants a *mappedBy* Attribute since its the inversed Side of the association. But as it seems, I can write **anything I want as value**. (the right value would be "user_id" i think?)

So, when is this value ever used or checked?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you're right, checked it in my project - no error is issued. It affects the way the entities are loaded (set `fetch="EAGER"` inside `OneToMany` and you'll get your error), mainly it sets the owner side on a comment object when hydrating data (there's a bit more magic going under the hood which is hard to understand). I'd post an issue in doctrine bug tracker, it's a source of errors that are hard to debug if you misspelled a field name.

---

You need to specify `inversedBy` as well:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="_commentsAuthored")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 *
 */
protected $_author;
```

<s>It should be used when you do retrieve the value of `_commentsAuthored` and try to do something with it (e.g., count it)</s>

Comment: The value of inversedBy is also ignored/not evaluated.
Getting a user from the db and calling $user->commentsAuthored->count() works as expceted.
Same with $comment->author, which returns the correct User object...

Comment: @MatthiasBayer are your annotations used at all? I mean didn't you convert XML/Yaml mapping to annotation?

Comment: Annotations work correct and are written manually. No convert from other formats. Generated SQL is correct. As I said, I dont know where those values ever get used..

Comment: @MatthiasBayer Yeah you're right, checked it in my project - no error is issued. It affects the way the entities are loaded (set fetch="EAGER" and you'll get your error), mainly it sets the owner side on a comment object when hydrating data. I'd post an issue in doctrine bug tracker, it's a source of errors that are hard to debug if you misspelled a field name.

Comment: I could not reproduce this (by adding fetch="EAGER" in the OneToMany/ManyToOne Annotation). Could you please provide some coud or the link to the bugtracker?

Comment: [Doctrine Jira](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC). Need to register and log in to be able to create a new issue.

Comment: Sry I meant the link to the issue you posted... (if you did yet)

Comment: @MatthiasBayer Oh, no, i haven't yet. I meant I would post it there if I were you.