# OneToMany relationship errors when using eager loading

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using FOSUserBundle for my users, Alice for fixture generation, and FOSRestBundle. I have 2 entities: User and Shift. A user can have many shifts. Below are my entity classes, and this is the error I get when I try to login as a valid user:

[2015-08-11 18:50:47] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice: Undefined index: user" at /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php line 1758 {"exception":"[object]

EDIT: line 1758 of BasicEntityPersister is looking at the mappedBy value. Still not sure what is wrong with it though.

EDIT: Also found this related topic [Doctrine: Value of mappedBy ignored in OneToMany Association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10573756/doctrine-value-of-mappedby-ignored-in-onetomany-association)

If I remove the fetch="EAGER" values I can login, otherwise I get the above error. I've scoured over this for almost 3 hours now and can't make heads or tails of it.

My tables if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `username_canonical` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email_canonical` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `enabled` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last_login` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `expired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `expires_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `confirmation_token` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `password_requested_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `roles` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT '(DC2Type:array)',
  `credentials_expired` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `credentials_expire_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(16) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D64992FC23A8` (`username_canonical`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_8D93D649A0D96FBF` (`email_canonical`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `shift` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `break` double NOT NULL,
  `start_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `end_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=51 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

User Class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * User
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="user")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Data\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
     * @Assert\Length(
     *     min=3,
     *     max=255,
     *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
     *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
     *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
     * )
     * @Expose
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="phone", type="string", length=16)
     * @Expose
     */
    private $phone;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Shift", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $shifts;


    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->shifts = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return User
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set phone
     *
     * @param string $phone
     * @return User
     */
    public function setPhone($phone)
    {
        $this->phone = $phone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get phone
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getPhone()
    {
        return $this->phone;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return User
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }

    /**
     * Add shifts
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Shift $shifts
     * @return User
     */
    public function addShift(\AppBundle\Entity\Shift $shifts)
    {
        $this->shifts[] = $shifts;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove shifts
     *
     * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Shift $shifts
     */
    public function removeShift(\AppBundle\Entity\Shift $shifts)
    {
        $this->shifts->removeElement($shifts);
    }

    /**
     * Get shifts
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getShifts()
    {
        return $this->shifts;
    }
}
```

Shift Class:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\ExclusionPolicy;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation\Expose;

/**
 * Shift
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Data\Repository\ShiftRepository")
 * @ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Shift
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="integer")
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="shifts", fetch="EAGER")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="break", type="float")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $break;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="start_time", type="datetime")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $startTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="end_time", type="datetime")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $endTime;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $createdAt;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     * @ORM\Column(name="updated_at", type="datetime")
     * @Expose
     */
    private $updatedAt;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set user
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @return Shift
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get user
     *
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * Set break
     *
     * @param float $break
     * @return Shift
     */
    public function setBreak($break)
    {
        $this->break = $break;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get break
     *
     * @return float 
     */
    public function getBreak()
    {
        return $this->break;
    }

    /**
     * Set startTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $startTime
     * @return Shift
     */
    public function setStartTime($startTime)
    {
        $this->startTime = $startTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get startTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getStartTime()
    {
        return $this->startTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set endTime
     *
     * @param \DateTime $endTime
     * @return Shift
     */
    public function setEndTime($endTime)
    {
        $this->endTime = $endTime;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get endTime
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getEndTime()
    {
        return $this->endTime;
    }

    /**
     * Set createdAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $createdAt
     * @return Shift
     */
    public function setCreatedAt($createdAt)
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get createdAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getCreatedAt()
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    /**
     * Set updatedAt
     *
     * @param \DateTime $updatedAt
     * @return Shift
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt($updatedAt)
    {
        $this->updatedAt = $updatedAt;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get updatedAt
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt()
    {
        return $this->updatedAt;
    }
}
```

Join query I need to perform that isn't working, and is throwing the following error:

```
$shiftsQuery = $this->createQueryBuilder('s1')
            ->addSelect('u')
            ->from('AppBundle:Shift', 's2')
            ->leftJoin('s1.user', 'u')
            ->where('u = :user')
            ->andWhere('s1.user = :user AND s2.user != :user')
            ->andWhere('s2.startTime BETWEEN s1.startTime AND s1.endTime OR s2.endTime BETWEEN s1.startTime AND s1.endTime')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->groupBy('s1.id')
        ;

        $result = $shiftsQuery
            ->getQuery()
            ->setFetchMode('AppBundle\Entity\User', 'shifts', \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata::FETCH_EAGER)
            ->getResult();
```

Error:

Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::semanticalError('line 0, col 62 near 'u, AppBundle:Shift': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Shift has no association named user', object(QueryException)) in /var/www/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php line 483

Comment: Fixed the login issue by removing fetch="EAGER" from the User entity, but something still isn't right. When working on a join query in my repository I get the following error regardless of what my leftJoin statement looks like: QueryException::semanticalError('line 0, col 62 near 'u, AppBundle:Shift': Error: Class AppBundle\Entity\Shift has no association named user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Shift.php entity, $user property has not correct annotation, try this:

```
/**
 * @var User
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="shifts", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Expose
 **/
private $user;
```

and then either make php doctine:schema:update --force or doctine:migrations:diff and then migrate up.

Comment: So as a result of that the shift table has a column named user_id in it instead of user?

Comment: Given the update you provided (thanks), how would a query look to select all shifts, and join the user for each shift into the result? So each Shift entity in the result has the user property, which is the User object. Check the original post, I added the query I'm trying to perform to the bottom of it and the corresponding error.

Answer (score 0):

Dan Mironis' annotation comment above was part of the problem. The other part, was how I was defining my fixtures. After making this update the query in my original post works as expected. I was just randomly assigning a user id on the shifts, so I updated it from:

```
AppBundle\Entity\Shift:
    shift{1..50}:
        userId: <numberBetween(1, 2)>
        break: <numberBetween(1, 8)>
        startTime: <dateTimeBetween('8AM', '12PM')>
        endTime: <dateTimeBetween($startTime, '+8 hours')>
```

to:

AppBundle\Entity\Shift:
    shift{1..20}:
        user: @user2
        break: 
        startTime: 
        endTime:

```
shift{21..40}:
    user: @user3
    break: <numberBetween(1, 8)>
    startTime: <dateTimeBetween('now', '+3 days')>
    endTime: <dateTimeBetween('now', '+3 days')>

shift{41..60}:
    user: @user4
    break: <numberBetween(1, 8)>
    startTime: <dateTimeBetween('now', '+3 days')>
    endTime: <dateTimeBetween('now', '+3 days')>

shift{61..80}:
    user: @user5
    break: <numberBetween(1, 8)>
    startTime: <dateTimeBetween('now', '+3 days')>
    endTime: <dateTimeBetween('now', '+3 days')>
```